# Is there a way for me to download all the tweets made by all twitter users in a particular region?

Tags: python, twitter, nlp

Is there a way for me to download all the tweets made by all twitter users in a particular region (say the USA) over a particular time period(say a week starting Nov. 15th and ending Nov 22nd) using Python? This is for an NLP task. Right now I am able to download the tweets related to certain topics which I search for and only the tweets being made while the program is running. I want to be able to get past tweets for a data mining/NLP task regardless of the topic.

Comment: If you googled the same query(as your qquestion) you couldve easily found out about quite a few Python modules which let you access the twitter API

Comment: I did google the question but all the results were filtering the twitter results and returning only the tweets including the search topic. I wanted to build a corpus of tweets for an NLP task which include all the tweets in a region.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You can.

Use [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/)

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''

access_token_key = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth1 = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth1.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, tweet):
        print 'Ran on_status'

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print 'Error: ' + repr(status_code)
        return False

    def on_data(self, data):
        print 'Ok, this is actually running'


l = StreamListener()
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth1, listener=l)
setTerms = ['twitter']
streamer.filter(track = setTerms)
```

In `stream.filter()` you can specify the region, for more [details](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations)

```
stream.filter(locations=[ "here you can define a region by listing the lang/lat" ], track=terms)
```

If you have a specific defined region, you can check that in the listner

```
def on_status(self, status):
      if status.coordinates .. :
```

Comment: this is going to return only the tweets which contain the term 'twitter' right? I wanted to be able to get all the tweets regardless of content.